# Applet deck of cards no display?

Tags: java, image, applet, awt, imageicon

I have a program that has a deck of cards, shuffles the deck and then gets 10 random cards and displays them in two rows of five each.  I have the program compiled, and the html page compiles, but when I run the html page, the appletviewer is blank...why is this?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class Cards1 extends Applet{
Image[] image = new Image[52];

public void init() {
    image[0] = getImage(getDocumentBase( ),"images/c1.gif");
    image[1] = getImage(getDocumentBase( ),"images/c2.gif");
    // ...
    image[48] = getImage(getDocumentBase( ), "images/h10.gif");
    image[49] = getImage(getDocumentBase( ), "images/hj.gif");
    image[50] = getImage(getDocumentBase( ), "images/hq.gif");
    image[51] = getImage(getDocumentBase( ), "images/hk.gif");
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
     //Shuffle
    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        int index = (int)(Math.random() * image.length);
        Image temp = image[i];
        image[i] = image[index];
        image[index] = temp;
    }

    //Display first row
    int index = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 294; j += 71) {
        g.drawImage(image[index++], 10 + j, 10, this);
    }

    //Display second row
    index = 5;
    for(int j = 0; j < 294; j += 71) {
        g.drawImage(image[index++], 10 + j, 106, this);
    }
}
}
```

//html code

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>DisplayCards</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet code = "DeckofCards1.class" width = 8000 height = 8000> </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the applet?  What URL?  Or failing that at least, what is the structure of the server in relation to HTML & images?

Comment: Try using public void paintComponent(Graphics g) then call super.paintComponent(g)

Comment: @MichaelArdan Try using `@Override` notation when doing that yourself. ;)

Comment: @MichaelArdan I get an error message from the command prompt saying the super.paintComponent(g) symbol cannot be found.

Comment: what is the @Override notation?

Comment: The code for the applet is "Cards1".  When I use appletviewer DisplayCards.html via the command prompt, an applet pops up, but with a blank screen and no cards

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah. I thought he already knew that he needs to override the method.

Comment: *"what is the Override notation?"* It will tell you if the code being changed actually overrides anything.  In the case of @MichaelArdan suggestion, it would warn that method does not exist.

Comment: There is not an error message per se, but I"m solely curious about why my programs compile and run, but the appletviewer does not display anything?

Answer (score 0):

First, you applet class has the name `Cards1` while the HTML code has `DeckofCards1.class` which I feel should have been `Cards1.class`.

Also, it seems there is some other applet class file `DeckofCards1.class` in the directory where `Cards1.class` exists which must be a blank applet.